# Generate openapi/swagger js client, without having to use npm or nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a swagger 2.0 api specification and I would like to generate an API client in javascript for it. The issue is, that the generator I am currently using (`org.openapi.generator" version '6.4.0'`) also creates a node.js project.
Nodejs modules can't be resolved by the browser (that's expected) but I can't host the javascript on a node server (I use springboot). I want to have a static version of the npm module openapi creates that can be included using standard ES6 syntax.

I tried to build the generated code and create a bundle using `browserify` but I have issues accessing the generated classes (everything is undefined).
But I doubt that this is the correct procedure, as using openapi in that way probably is a common thing to do.

#### Generation

I generate the javascript using the gradle openapi-generator plugin (6.4.0) like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "javascript"
    inputSpec = "${projectDir}/src/[redacted]/api.json";
    outputDir = "${projectDir}/src/frontend/static/lib/apiClient"
    configOptions = [
            usePromises: 'true',
            emitModelMethods: 'true',
            outputFileSuffix: ".js",
            useES6: "true"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `openapi generator` has a spring boot generator as well.  Since you are using spring boot for your backend already, have you considered using that generator instead?  If that is 100% out of the question, can you share your cli commands that you are using to generate the server?  I assume you are using the [`nodejs-express-server`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/nodejs-express-server.md) generator.  If so, that is a server generator and it is currently in beta.  I'd suggest one of the javascript generators instead.

Comment: I actually already use Spring but for the backend. I need to generate the code for the frontend. I generate the javascript using gradle. (I added the code to the question)